# Increasing set or decreasing set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I know this is probably trivial but I am confused on how we determine a set is increasing or decreasing. For example suppose we have a set $\{E_j\}_{1}^{\infty}\subset M$ where $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Then supposedly $$\left\{\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j\right\}_{k=1}^\infty$$ is an increasing sequence of sets and $$\left\{\bigcup_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j\right\}_{k=1}^\infty$$ is an decreasing sequence of sets

Why is that the case?

Comment: Still do not understand why though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sequence $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset A_3 \supset \ldots $ is decreasing,

a sequence $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset A_3 \subset \ldots $ is increasing.

In this case, for $$B_k := \bigcap_{j=k}^\infty E_j$$

we have $B_k = B_{k+1} \cap E_k \subset B_{k+1}$, so the sequence $(B_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is increasing.

Analogously, for $$C_k := \bigcup_{j=k}^\infty E_j$$

we get $C_k = C_{k+1} \cup E_k \supset C_{k+1}$, so the sequence $(C_k)$ is decreasing.

For another example, if we say $$B'_k := \bigcap_{j=1}^k E_j$$

we get a decreasing sequence $(B'_k)$ (unlike $(B_k)$), since $B'_{k+1} = B'_k \cap E_{k+1} \subset B'_k$.

Comment: I still don't understand this, do you have any references I can refer to? I feel like this is really basic and I still can't see it

Comment: $B_{k} = E_{k} \cap E_{k+1} \cap E_{k+2} \cap E_{k+3} \cap \ldots$, $~~B_{k+1} = E_{k+1} \cap E_{k+2} \cap E_{k+3} \cap \ldots$, therefore $B_k = E_{k} \cap (E_{k+1} \cap E_{k+2} \cap E_{k+3} \cap \ldots) = E_k \cap B_{k+1}$.

Comment: By this logic $C_k = E_k\cup E_{k+1} \cup \ldots$, $C_{k+1} = E_{k+1}\cup E_{k+2} \cup \ldots$, therefore $C_k = E_k \cup(E_{k+1}\cup E_{k+2} \cup \ldots) = E_k\cup C_{k+1}$ how does this show that it is decreasing?

Comment: We've just shown that $C_k \supset C_{k+1}$. Repeat this argument for all $k$, and you get $C_1 \supset C_2 \supset C_3 \supset \ldots$

Comment: $C_1 = E_1\cup C_{2}$ so this shows $C_1\supset C_2$? yes or no?

Comment: Yes. $C_1 = E_1 \cup C_2$ means that $C_1$ contains exactly those elements contained either in $E_1$ or $C_2$. Since this means that $C_1$ contains all elements in $C_2$, we get $C_1 \supset C_2$.

Comment: Ok, so how about when $F_k = \bigcap_{1}^{\infty}E_j$ then would we have $F_1\supset F_2\supset \ldots$?

Comment: Technically yes. In this case $F_1 = F_2 = F_3 = \ldots$, since $F_k$ does not depend on $k$.

Comment: great thank you I understand it now

Answer (score 1):

The sequence index is $k$. So define $$I(k) = \bigcap_{j=k}^\infty E_j$$

Then $x \in I(k)$ iff for **all** $j \ge k$ we have $x \in E_j$. So it's "easier" to be in $I(k+1)$ because then you only have to be in $E_j$ for **all** $j \ge k+1$, which is fewer sets. And if $x$ is in $I(k)$, then it is certainly in $I(k+1)$ for that reason, hence the sequence is increasing: $$\forall k: I(k) \subseteq I(k+1)\text{.}$$

For the union $$U(k) = \bigcup_{j=k}^\infty E_j$$ the oppossite holds: if $x \in U(k+1)$ then $x \in E_j$ for **some** $j \ge k+1$. The $j$ that works is also $\ge k$ so $x \in U(k)$. So this sequence decreases:

$$ \forall k :U(k+1) \subseteq U(k)\text{.}$$

Comment: I am still lost, where can I get a basic understanding of this. Is this in set theory?

Comment: @Wolfy Yes, but it's really basic logic

Comment: and my logic is below basic so I do not know what to do to understand this

Comment: @Wolfy you have to know what the notations mean.

Comment: I do know what the notation means but I do not know what the subscripts means as in $\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j$ means. I know that it is an intersections of sets but from $j = k,\ldots,\infty$ I do not understand

Comment: @Wolfy You have to understand the concept of a sequence of sets.

Comment: A sequence of sets is just a number of sets in a space?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39785/discussion-between-henno-brandsma-and-wolfy).

Comment: I am confused on the union part still why is that decresing?

Comment: To be in a union of the tail from $k$ onwards, you either are in $E_k$ or you are in the tail from $k+1$ onwards. So the latter set is smaller, as you potentially lose all members of $E_k$ that are not in later $E_j$.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, so we have $\mu\left(\bigcup_{j=k}^{\infty}E_j\right) = \cup E_k \cup E_{k+1} \cup \ldots$ how does that imply that $E_k \supset E_{k+1} \supset \ldots$?

Comment: @Wolfy It does not. Define $U_k = \bigcup_{j=k}^\infty E_j$. Then $U_k \supseteq U_{k+1} \supseteq \ldots$

Comment: I don't understand why this is throwing me off so much where can I understand this? I am pretty sure this is pretty basic

Comment: Is there another way I can see this I do not understand why I cant see it :(

Comment: @Wolfy Suppose $x \in U_{k+1}$. Then there is some $j \ge k+1$ such that $x \in E_j$. So there is some $j \ge k$ such that $x \in E_j$ (**that same $j$ works**), so $x \in U_k$. Done: $U_{k+1} \subseteq U_k$.

Comment: @Wolfy this is the argument I just gave. No more, no less. Cannot be simplified.

Comment: @Wolfy it should say $\supseteq$ not $\supset$ as you cannot garantuee properness of inclusions.